# putting frameboxes right up against each other to make a grid

Tags: spacing, boxes

I am trying to make a simple **grid**, using two loops of `\framebox` (across, then down).

I am having a problem making the frameboxes overlap each other perfectly.
The vertical spacing seems to work ok:  `\setlength\lineskip{\fboxrule}`

But I can't get the horizontal spacing to work.  I think it is a problem with inter-word spacing, but I am not sure.

I want to keep the grid as general as possible (answer should able to cope with different size grids).

And, yes, I know about `TikZ` and `tabular` environments to achieve similar results; but I don't want to use these.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\i
\newcount\j
\newcommand\loopy[3]{
    #1=0
    {\loop \ifnum#1<#2 \advance#1 by1 
    #3
    \repeat}
}
\newcommand{\row}[3]
% \row{3}{2}{5} means 3 boxes of 2 by 5
    {\loopy{\i}{#1}%
    {\framebox(#2,#3)[]{}\hspace*{-0.5\fboxsep}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}}%
    }
\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{2cm}
\setlength\lineskip{\fboxrule}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
\loopy{\j}{2}{\row{4}{1}{1}\par}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line:

`{\framebox(#2,#3)[]{}\hspace*{-0.5\fboxsep}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}}`

to

`{\framebox(#2,#3)[]{}\hspace*{\fboxrule}}`